# How to search for a particular value in a column of values and replace with that particular value in Big Query SQL?

Tags: sql, bigdata, google-bigquery

How can I search for a particular value 'xyz' in a column of values at id level and replace all of them with 'xyz' at id level if it's found. Here is my sample input/output as below.

```
****
 - Input :-
****

id,value 
123,'abc'
123,'abc'
123,'xyz'
456,'def'
456,'def'
456,'def'
```

**`Output:-`**

```
id,value 
123,'xyz'
123,'xyz'
123,'xyz'
456,'def'
456,'def'
456,'def'
```

Comment: I don't get it what you need here, can you be a bit more explicit and detail what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpreted the example - you look for all id's where value is 'xyz', and change the value for such ids to 'xyz'.
Then the following LEFT JOIN should do it:

```
SELECT a.id, IF(b.value IS NULL, a.value, 'xyz') FROM (
SELECT a.id, a.value, b.value FROM T a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT id FROM T WHERE value = 'xyz') b)
```